# hold thread until handler finish android

Tags: android, multithreading

Hi I want to pause my thread until handler finish.
I test synchronized but it's not work properly.

```
synchronized (handle) 
{
      handle.sendMessage(msg); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a CountDownLatch: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html